# Sage: How to CNFEncode?

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to use the [CNFEncode](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/sat/sage/sat/converters/polybori.html?highlight=cnfencoder) module in sagemath. After I got a few strange errors I tried to simply copy and execute the code snippet provided with the documentation inside Sage Cloud. But I got some errors

```
sage: B.<a,b,c> = BooleanPolynomialRing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ce036e32ef87> in <module>()
----> 1 B = BooleanPolynomialRing; (a, b, c,) = B._first_ngens(3)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_first_ngens'
```

I managed to got past that with:

```
B = BooleanPolynomialRing(3,["a","b","c"])
```

But after a few lines I'm stuck again, here:

```
sage: B = BooleanPolynomialRing(3,["a","b","c"])
sage: from sage.sat.converters.polybori import CNFEncoder
sage: from sage.sat.solvers.dimacs import DIMACS
sage: fn = tmp_filename()
sage: solver = DIMACS(filename=fn)
sage: e = CNFEncoder(solver, B)
sage: e.clauses_sparse(a*b + a + 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0dac365c6fab> in <module>()
----> 1 e.clauses_sparse(a*b + a + Integer(1))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I tried to change the last line, but I simply got to another error:

```
sage: e.clauses_sparse("a*b + a + 1")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-081f32dddbcf> in <module>()
----> 1 e.clauses_sparse("a*b + a + 1")

/projects/sage/sage-6.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/sat/converters/polybori.py in clauses_sparse(self, f)
    284         # any zero block of f+1
    285
--> 286         blocks = self.zero_blocks(f+1)
    287         C = [dict([(variable, 1-value) for (variable, value) in b.iteritems()]) for b in blocks ]
    288

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I'm pretty stuck with this and I can't find any kind of help in the documentation (beside the same code I can't get to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot parentheses. Instead of

```
sage: B.<a,b,c> = BooleanPolynomialRing
```

either write, using the condensed syntax,

```
sage: B.<a,b,c> = BooleanPolynomialRing()
```

or use the more explicit syntax

```
sage: B = BooleanPolynomialRing(3,['a','b','c'])
sage: a, b, c = B.gens()
```

in which the first line sets the display names
of the polynomial variables as a, b, c,
and the second line creates Python variables
with values these polynomial variables.

If you want to define this in a .py file,
you need the explicit syntax and appropriate imports.